# wget returns only (an expected) "401 unauthorized" but no html

Tags: wget

In using a browser to test our website, I enter a purposefully incorrect username/password, and get an html page back from the application telling me the login has failed and to "Please check my username & password, then try again".  Viewing the source for this page, I can't find a "401" embedded anywhere.

But mimicking the above using wget:

```
wget http://servername:8011/ui/login.do --post-data="loginId=NotAUser&password=NotAPassword" -U Mozilla -o log.txt
```

the output file contains "401 Unauthorized", but none of the html mentioned above.

Is there a way to get the html page I was expecting, and just check for the 401 return code with a "$?" test?

Answer (score 1):

The "401 Unauthorised" you're getting is in the headers of the response from the server.  A 401 response doesn't have an HTML - it's just an error code.

The page that you describe in the browser is actually generated by the browser, not sent back from the server.  Browser vendors generate meaningful error pages rather than just displaying "401 Unauthorized" or "404 Page Not Found" to the user.  There's no way to get the HTML code you're seeing using wget because it's not part of the HTTP conversation.

Answer (score 0):

`wget` used to stop on a non-200 response code and not retrieve the body of the reply. It has been updated to correct this behaviour and versions 1.14-1 and later should work as expected:

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=247985

If you're stuck with an older version or can't get it to work, why not try `curl` instead?

https://superuser.com/questions/253826/how-to-use-wget-to-download-http-error-pages